# Type I error for composite null hypothesis

Tags: probability

Let $X ∼ \operatorname{Uniform}(\theta,\theta+1)$. We are testing $H_0: \theta \le 0$ versus $H_1: \theta>0$. If the test rejects $H_0$ if $X > 0.95$, how do I compute the probability of a type I error?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $H_0$ is composite. Let $\Theta_0=\{\theta:\theta\le 0\}$. The Type I error probabilities are defined by
$$\{P_{\theta}(X>0.95)\mid \theta\in \Theta_0\}=[0,0.05]$$
This is because $P_\theta(X>0.95)$ is zero if $\theta<-0.05$ and for $\theta \in (-0.05,0]$, the probability is given by $\theta+1-0.95$ which lies in $(0,0.05]$. Note that the size of the test is given by
$$\sup_{\theta\in\Theta_0} P_{\theta}(X>0.95)=0.05$$

Comment: Thank you - very helpful!!

Comment: See related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948223/hypothesis-test-for-sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables